# pasar consulta de access a sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

mi consulta es como puedo pasar esta consulta de `access` a `sql` ya que estoy haciendo un proyecto en `visual studio 2013` y en el dtaset no me la reconoce. Ya tengo la base de datos conectada en `VS`, y no funciona la consulta.

```
SELECT HISTORIAL.FECHA, HISTORIAL.APTO, HISTORIAL.BANCO, HISTORIAL.REFERENCIA, HISTORIAL.FECHAOPERACION, HISTORIAL.MES, HISTORIAL.MONTO, HISTORIAL.dolares, HISTORIAL.tasa
FROM HISTORIAL
WHERE (((Month([HISTORIAL]![FECHA]))=[?]))
```

La consulta la edito de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT FECHA, APTO, BANCO, REFERENCIA, FECHAOPERACION, MES, MONTO, dolares, tasa
FROM HISTORIAL WHERE  month(fecha) = 9
```

Y el error que tira es dice:

> la funcion month no esta definida en la funcion.

Comment: Hola. La fecha debe estar en formato "YYYY/MM/DD", lo que supongo ya está hecho en la base de datos de tu SQL SErver y debe estar encerrada entre apóstrofos.  

month('fecha') = 9

Comment: En `sql server` si la columna es de tipo `date/datetime` o cualquier otro similar, no tienen formato. Se almacenan en binario, y se muestran con el formato que solicita el cliente (o por el idioma asociado al login que se conecta). La función `month` no necesita apóstrofes, y puede usar una conversión implicita incluso de una columna tipo `varchar`. Es más si no puede convertirlo a fecha da un error de conversión. 
Además ese error no es del motor SQL porque no aparece en el catalogo de sys.messages. También puedes usar `where datepart(mm,fecha)=9`

Comment: A mi el error me da pinta de que está intentando antes de mandar la query al SQL, usar alguna función propia de tú proyecto o similar. Pero deberías de poder tracear lo que ocurre. [VS depurar código](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022). Y ver lo que le llega explicitamente al Sql Server,[Sql Server profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Los comentarios asumen que es SQL Server, pero de ser así no habría un error en la consulta sino en la forma de enviarla. Necesitamos más detalles para poder responder adecuadamente incluyendo el gestor de base de datos.

Comment: la base de datos está en acces 2016, logré que no me diera error de esta forma SELECT FECHA, APTO, MES, MONTO, dolares, tasa, FORMAPAGO, FECHAOPERACION, REFERENCIA, BANCO
FROM     HISTORIAL
WHERE  ('[month] fecha' = ?) pero no me filtra, no me da ningun resultado, el campo fecha esta formateado como fecha, pero no se como paserle el parametro como tal. la idea es que si pongo 9 me muestre todos los registros de septiembre

Comment: Muestra el programa y cómo construyes la sentencia.

Comment: la sentencia la construyo con el data source de visual studio 2013, creo un dataset y luego con el query builder, osea que el select SELECT FECHA, APTO, MES, MONTO, dolares, tasa, FORMAPAGO, FECHAOPERACION, REFERENCIA, BANCO FROM HISTORIAL WHERE ('[month] fecha' = ?)  lo crea el query builder, he probado cambiando el parametro tipo text, int32, single, date y nada.

Comment: hola, aun no resuelvo, la consulta no me arroja resultados, con select sin parametros funciona, pero necesito hacer el filtro.